# Oracle: Using subquery in a trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, subquery

How can I work around the Oracle's limitation of not allowing subqueries in triggers.

Here's an example trigger I'm trying to create, but am unable to because I can't use a subquery.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_w_subquery
AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT ON project_archiving
FOR EACH ROW WHEN (old.archiving_status <> new.archiving_status
  AND new.archiving_status = 1
  AND (SELECT offer FROM projects WHERE projnum = :new.projnum) IS NULL
)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO offer_log (offer, status, date)
  VALUES (null, 9, sysdate);
END;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This trigger would do it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_w_subquery
AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT ON project_archiving
FOR EACH ROW WHEN (old.archiving_status <> new.archiving_status
  AND new.archiving_status = 1
)
DECLARE
  l_offer projects.offer%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT offer INTO l_offer 
  FROM projects 
  WHERE projnum = :new.projnum;

  IF l_offer IS NULL THEN
    INSERT INTO offer_log (offer, status, date)
    VALUES (null, 9, sysdate);
  END IF;
END;
```

I have assumed that the select from projects will always find a row; if not it will raise a NO_DATA_FOUND exception that you may need to handle.

Comment: Just a warning that, if you use multi-table inserts (inserting into both project and project_archiving), you may end up with a mutating table error. As such it is preferable to put the logic where the original insert is, rather than rely on a trigger.

Comment: Where did the type projects.offer%TYPE come from? Does it refer to the type of the offer in the table projects? Or perhaps more tantalizingly, does anyone have any good resources to recommend for learning this?

Comment: @HaakonLøtveit https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-2E4B6BBA-08B5-473A-901D-738BD00ABF47

Answer (score 6):

I expect that you want something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_w_subquery
AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT ON project_archiving
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (old.archiving_status <> new.archiving_status
  AND new.archiving_status = 1)
DECLARE
  l_offer projects.offer%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT offer 
    INTO l_offer
    FROM projects 
   WHERE projnum = :new.projnum;

  IF( l_offer IS NULL )
  THEN
    INSERT INTO offer_log (offer, status, date)
      VALUES (null, 9, sysdate);
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Sorry, Justin. I can only select one answer as corrent one. This time you were beaten by a simple exception warning :-) The up vote you deserved, never the less.

Answer (score 2):

Can you put the condition into the action (between BEGIN and END) instead of in the 'whether it fires'?  Yes, it means that the trigger body might be fired more often - but if it gets you around the problem...

Comment: The cost of executing the subquery is most likely much higher than the overhead for firing a trigger, so I guess it doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: Attempted BEGIN IF (SELECT offer FROM projects WHERE projnum = :new.projnum) IS NULL 
THEN INSERT INTO etc. However, it Oracle throws an error as it encounteres the SELECT in that statement. It just doesn't expect it.

Comment: I'm not sufficiently familiar with PL/SQL to know whether that's a plausible way of writing the code in the trigger.  It looks good; other systems that I know would require some sort of assignment from the SELECT (with an INTO clause and a variable), and then check the variable, or something along those lines.  There's probably a description of the limitations on triggers in the manuals.  Also - can you call a procedure in the action part?  If so, maybe that will work for you?  (Pass the relevant values as parameters.)