# SQL Triggers containing sub-queries possible?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, subquery

Would appreciate some assistance; I am using Oracle.

Current code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_SAMPLETRG
BEFORE INSERT ON CATEGORY_Details
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE W_YEARSALIVE NUMBER(3);
BEGIN

  SELECT ((SYSDATE - animal_origindate)/365) INTO W_YEARSALIVE
  FROM animal
  WHERE animal_no = :NEW.animal_no;

  IF W_YEARSALIVE < 180 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20005, 'The animal has existed for only ' || W_YEARSALIVE || ' years');
  ELSIF W_YEARSALIVE IS NULL THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20005, 'The animal has to have a origin date entered before evaluation.');
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('The animal is over 180 years and is not yet extinct and has been added');
  END IF;
END;
```

When I am adding an animal into the category_details table, if the animal has an origin date (in years), of less than 180, OR if it does not have an origin date, it will not be added and an exception error will be returned.

Now, **I don't require the trigger to be evaluated on every animal that I insert into the category_details table, I only want to add/evaluate the trigger on the animals from only 4 of these different categories: Monera, Prokaryota, Plantae, Eukaryota**

i.e. **any other different category, i.e. Animalia, Vegetabilia, should not even be evaluated at all, aka, no restrictions on any insertion of an animal that are related to those (or 'other') categories.**

I've tried adding a WHEN statement with a subquery like below:
    WHEN (:NEW.kingdom_no IN (SELECT kingdom_no FROM kingdom WHERE kingdom_name IN    ('Monera', 'Prokaryota', 'Plantae', 'Eukaryota'))

but it looks like you can't add subqueries into TRIGGERS...

I found this thread: [Oracle: Using subquery in a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909156/oracle-using-subquery-in-a-trigger)

However, it appears that only looks neat with 1 value/category, whereas I have 4, and would have to declare 4 variables?

I was also trying to put a subquery within an IF statement, however I don't think that is syntactically valid in SQL/Oracle.

Any assistance is appreciated thank you.

EDIT: Table structure is simply:
3 tables: animals, category_details and kingdom
category_details' table has the following attributes: animal_no, kingdom_no
animals' table has following attributes: animal_no, animal_origindate
kingdoms' table has the following attributes: kingdom_no, kingdom_name

Answer (score 1):

As, according to the Oracle documentation **the [WHEN] condition cannot include a subquery** you must put this part inside the trigger body itself e.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_sampletrg
  BEFORE INSERT ON category_details
  FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE

  w_kingdom_name kingdom.kingdom_name%TYPE;
  w_yearsalive   NUMBER(3);

BEGIN

  SELECT kingdom_name
  INTO w_kingdom_name
  FROM kingdom
  WHERE kingdom_no = :new.kingdom_no;

  IF w_kingdom_name IN ('Monera', 'Prokaryota', 'Plantae', 'Eukaryota') THEN

    SELECT months_between(sysdate, animal_origindate)/12
    INTO w_yearsalive
    FROM animal
    WHERE animal_no = :new.animal_no;

    IF w_yearsalive < 180 THEN
      raise_application_error(-20005, 'The animal has existed for only ' || w_yearsalive || ' years');
    ELSIF w_yearsalive IS NULL THEN
      raise_application_error(-20005, 'The animal has to have a origin date entered before evaluation.');
    END IF;

  END IF;

END;
```

Comment: Thank you. One concern I had prior to this post was, what is the difference between "((SYSDATE - animal_origindate)/365)" and what you have done, months_between(sysdate, animal_origindate)/12?

Don't they produce the same output? If so, what is the significant difference between the two that you would choose one over the other?

Comment: Using `(sysdate-animal_origindate)/365` you assume that each year has 365 days, which is not the case. The `months_between` function takes account of years with differing lengths and so gives an accurate result in the `w_yearsalive`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make subqueries inline in PL/SQL at all. What you can do is something like this:

```
SELECT k.kingdom_name
INTO   l_kingdom
FROM   kingdom k
WHERE  k.kingdom_no = :NEW.kingdom_no;

IF l_kingdom in ('Monera','Prokaryota','Plantae','Eukaryota' THEN
   -- Do what needs to be done
END IF;
```

In general you can do all the DML(select,update,insert etc.) you want in a row trigger. The exception that often annoys people is that you cannot do DML on the table on which the trigger is attached - in your case CATEGORY_DETAILS.

Comment: Thank you. One question though, why is it that performing DML commands on the table on which the trigger is attached is annoying? Is it because of the fact that "you cannot make subqueries inline in PL/SQL at all"? My apologies for not understanding the first time.

Comment: People new to triggers in Oracle often find that it would be nice to select from the same table to check how the new row correspond to the rows already in the the table. You can actually create such a trigger and it will compile and run for single row DML operations. But if you have a statement that updates or inserts several rows you will see an exception: ORA-04091: table XXXX is mutating, trigger/function may not see it. There are ways of working around it - but none of them are nice.

Comment: Excellent thank you. Also, may I ask if you would happen to know why my ELSE statement is not executing properly? i.e. after inserting a record that is not catched by the exception and is under the 4 kingdoms/categories, how come the output line is not appearing? I only witnessed the "Inserted 1 row" comment. I am pretty certain it was outputted before, am I missing something obvious?

Comment: My guess is that it works - but dbms_output only shows if you have done "set serveroutput on" in your sql*plus session.

Comment: One last thing, would you happen to know if it would be possible to retrieve data from another table in the trigger?

That is, in my case, can the output of the raise_application_error function be data from another table?
i.e. kingdom.kingdom_name

All I receive (after incorporating that into the error function) is:
LS-00357: Table,View Or Sequence reference 'kingdom.kingdom_name' not allowed in this context

Comment: I am going to assume that I will need to have a 'SELECT [columns] INTO' statement and assign the value to a variable, which I can use as a 'reference' to the value from the other table? Or is there perhaps a more efficient way to go about it? Thank you

Comment: That would be the way to do it.