# Trigger for checking values for inserting

Tags: plsql, triggers

I have two tables that here are involved from two different schemas.

Schema services and table task  -- column ID

Schme mona_internal and table officius_unos  -- column task

I need trigger when inserting in column task table officius_unos to check does exist inserting value in column id from table task. If exist, to continue inserting, it doesn't exist to raise the error.

Here is the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER mona_internal.PROBA_PROBA 
    BEFORE INSERT ON OFFICIUS_UNOS 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    DECLARE
        task_provera number(10);

        BEGIN
            select id into task_provera from servis.task
            where id=:new.task;

            if (task_provera is null)
                then raise_application_error(-20101, 'No task');
                else insert into mona_internal.OFFICIUS_UNOS (task) values (:new.task);
            end if;    

        END;
```

The trigger is compiled, but the problem appears when trying to insert a new value in column task table officius_unos,
it returns me this message

```
insert into officius_unos (task) values (291504);

    Error report -
    ORA-00036: maximum number of recursive SQL levels (50) exceeded
    ORA-00036: maximum number of recursive SQL levels (50) exceeded
    ORA-06512: at "MONA_INTERNAL.PROBA_PROBA", line 5
    ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'MONA_INTERNAL.PROBA_PROBA'
    ORA-06512: at "MONA_INTERNAL.PROBA_PROBA", line 10
```

And value 291504 exist in table task in column id.

P.S. Also try to solve this problem with check constraint, but there are forbidden subqueries. The solution that I used to overcome my problem is here

[Oracle: Using subquery in a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909156/oracle-using-subquery-in-a-trigger)

Comment: `else insert into mona_internal.OFFICIUS_UNOS (task) values (:new.task);` is not required. That's the cause of the error

Comment: Why don't you use a foreign key constraint instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to insert in an insert trigger.

If the trigger is successful Oracle will continue with the INSERT on its own.

So the immediate solution is to remove the INSERT from the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER mona_internal.PROBA_PROBA 
    BEFORE INSERT ON OFFICIUS_UNOS 
    FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE
    task_provera number(10);
BEGIN
    select id 
       into task_provera 
    from servis.task
    where id=:new.task;

    if (task_provera is null) then 
      raise_application_error(-20101, 'No task');
    end if;
    // nothing do do here
END;
```

However the above still isn't correct. If the `id` doesn't exist in `servis.tak` the SELECT will throw a `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception.

One solution to that is to use an aggregate function that will always return one row. If no rows match the WHERE criteria, a NULL value is returned:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER mona_internal.PROBA_PROBA 
    BEFORE INSERT ON OFFICIUS_UNOS 
    FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE
    task_provera number(10);
BEGIN
    select max(id) 
       into task_provera 
    from servis.task
    where id=:new.task;

    if (task_provera is null) then 
      raise_application_error(-20101, 'No task');
    end if;
    // nothing do do here
END;
```

Or you could explicitely catch the exception:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER mona_internal.PROBA_PROBA 
    BEFORE INSERT ON OFFICIUS_UNOS 
    FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE
    task_provera number(10);
BEGIN
    select max(id) 
       into task_provera 
    from servis.task
    where id=:new.task;

    if (task_provera is null) then 
      raise_application_error(-20101, 'No task');
    end if;

EXCEPTION 
   WHEN NOT_DATA_FOUND THEN 
      raise_application_error(-20101, 'No task');
END;
```

---

But the correct approach is to use a foreign key constraint for something like that.

```
alter table mona_internal.PROBA_PROBA 
   add constraint fk_proba_task
   foreign key (task)
   references servis.task (id);
```

Then you don't need a trigger at all.

This requires that the user `mona_internal` is not only granted the `SELECT` privilege on servis.task, but also the `references` privilege:

To do that, run the following as the `SERVIS` user:

```
grant references on task to mona_internal;
```

Comment: Man, thank's a lot for detailed explanation, You clarify me a new things, that was bothering me